# Flyway baseline doesn't work unless schema_version table is in the database

Tags: java, flyway

In my Java application I have set:

```
flyway.setBaselineVersionAsString("7")
```

however on a brand new database which doesn't yet have the `schema_version` table Flyway doesn't consider the baseline setting and runs all migrations.

Is there a way to force the creation of `schema_version` table before migrations start, as I tried to create the table manually and the code worked fine. Or is there any other solution for that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which command are you running, [`baseline`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/baseline) or [`migrate`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate)?

If you are running `baseline` then you need to publish more configuration in order to establish what is wrong - as creating a `schema_version` table with a basline version is exactly what it does.

If you are running `migrate` the observed behaviour is correct - that is, on a non-Flyway managed database the `schema_version` table will be created and all migrations run. The one exception to this is if you have set `baselineOnMigrate` which will effectively run an implicit `baseline` before the `migrate` is started.

Creating the `schema_version` yourself is certainly something you should *not* be doing, you will completely compromise Flyways intelligence.

Comment: I am actually setting baselonOnMigrate to be true.
I set the base line using flyway.setBaselineVersionAsString("7")
then I use flyway.migrate()...
But still all migrations are executed starting from 1.

Comment: What is `schemas` set to? As per the [`baselineOnMigrate`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate) docs "Whether to automatically call baseline when migrate is executed against a non-empty schema with no metadata table". Are you pointing at a non-existing or empty schema?

Comment: Yes it's an empty schema that I am going to be doing migrations on, but sometimes I don't want all migrations to be done, I want only migrations from a certain version to be done. That's why I am using the setting of baseline, but migrations are still done from the beginning.

Comment: Try running the `baseline` command before `migrate`, I'm not in a position to test but if I recall correctly `baseline` will obey the `baselineVersion` in the event of a no/empty schema situation.

Comment: @MohamedAhmedTaherMohamed Did you get a result?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. 
I am doing what you are saying...
`Flyway flyway = new Flyway();`
`flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);`
`flyway.setBaselineVersionAsString("7");`
`flyway.migrate();`

Comment: @MohamedAhmedTaherMohamed No, test the `baseline` command, instead of `setBaselineOnMigrate`.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in this kind situation too many times. the way I do is detect the result of flyway.info().  If it is null, it means the schema has objects but no "schema_version" table - then set the baseline like you did.